# Is it possible to rotate a (Surface)UserControl by 180 degree?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

Is there a simple method that allows to rotate a UI element like for example a UserControl resp. a SurfaceUserControl by 180 degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx).

Comment: I don't really know what is meant by this point. I think it is the ratation center? So if I would like to rotate a UIElement that covers the whole screen by 180 degree I think I should use the center of the screen as the rotation center? Therefore I used point (512/384) as the rotation center, but it doesn't seem to work at all?

Comment: use (0.5, 0.5) which means "the center of the control".  this is the default too so you don't need to explicitly state the center point

Answer (score 2):

Apply a [rotate Transform](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx).

Comment: So simple and nevertheless I didn't thought of that